# best way to test a character for being from some category in .net

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, text, nlp

I need an efficient way to test a given character (System.Char) for being a consonant. Then I need the same thing for vowels. More generally I need an efficient implementation of the following interface, given the target set of characters is of some 20 chars. Please advise. Thanks!

```
using System;

public interface ITester
{
    Boolean IsInCategory(Char something);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok guys, I've run some tests. And here's what I got. The best way is to use precalculated map where each char is mapped to a boolean. (See IndexBased in the code below). HashSet as turned out is not the best one.
If anyone has more ideas, let me know.

```
[TestClass]
public class Runner
{
    public const Int32 NumberOfRuns = 10000;
    public const String TextSample = @"The Letter It was November. Although it was not yet late, the sky was dark when I turned into Laundress Passage. Father had finished for the day, switched off the shop lights and closed the shutters; but so I would not come home to darkness he had left on the light over the stairs to the flat. Through the glass in the door it cast a foolscap rectangle of paleness onto the wet pavement, and it was while I was standing in that rectangle, about to turn my key in the door, that I first saw the letter. Another white rectangle, it was on the fifth step from the bottom, where I couldn't miss it. I closed the door and put the shop key in its usual place behind Bailey's Advanced Principles of Geometry. Poor Bailey. No one has wanted his fat gray book for thirty years. Sometimes I wonder what he makes of his role as guardian of the bookshop keys. I don't suppose it's the destiny he had in mind for the masterwork that he spent two decades writing. A letter. For me. That was something of an event. The crisp-cornered envelope, puffed up with its thickly folded contents, was addressed in a hand that must have given the postman a certain amount of trouble. Although the style of the writing was old-fashioned, with its heavily embellished capitals and curly flourishes, my first impression was that it had been written by a child. The letters seemed untrained. Their uneven strokes either faded into nothing or were heavily etched into the paper. There was no sense of flow in the letters that spelled out my name.";
    private interface ITester
    {
        Boolean IsConsonant(Char something);
    }

    // results in millisecs: 14807, 16411, 15050, 
    private class HashSetBasedTester : ITester
    {
        private HashSet<Char> hash;
        public HashSetBasedTester()
        {
            this.hash = new HashSet<Char>("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz");
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return this.hash.Contains(Char.ToLower(something));
        }
    }

    // results in millisecs: 12270, 12495, 12853,
    private class HardcodedTester : ITester
    {
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            var lower = Char.ToLower(something);
            return lower == 'b' || lower == 'c' || lower == 'd' || lower == 'f' || lower == 'g' || lower == 'h' || lower == 'j' || lower == 'k' || lower == 'l' || lower == 'm' || lower == 'n' || lower == 'p' || lower == 'q' || lower == 'r' || lower == 's' || lower == 't' || lower == 'v' || lower == 'w' || lower == 'x' || lower == 'z';
        }
    }

    // WORST RESULTS
    // results in millisecs: 32140, 31549, 31856
    private class ListBasedTester : ITester
    {
        private List<Char> list;
        public ListBasedTester()
        {
            this.list = new List<Char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' };
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return this.list.Contains(Char.ToLower(something));
        }
    }

    // WINNER! (fastest and most consistent)
    // results in millisecs: 11335, 11349, 11386, 
    private class IndexBased : ITester
    {
        private Boolean[] map;
        private char min;
        private char max;
        public IndexBased()
        {
            var chars = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz".ToArray();
            this.min = chars.Min();
            this.max = chars.Max();
            var length = this.max - this.min + 1;
            this.map = new Boolean[length];
            foreach (var at in chars)
            {
                map[at - min] = true;
            }
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            something = Char.ToLower(something);
            return something <= this.max && something >= this.min && this.map[something - this.min];
        }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        var tester = new IndexBased(); // new HashSetBasedTester(); // new HardcodedTester(); // new ListBasedTester(); //
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfRuns; i++)
        {
            foreach (var at in TextSample)
            {
                var tested = tester.IsConsonant(at);
            }
        }
        Trace.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This set of tests doesn't do casting to lower/upper and we have much better results! Anyways the favorites/losers are the same. Check it out:

```
[TestClass]
public class Runner
{
    public const Int32 NumberOfRuns = 10000;
    public const String TextSample = @"The Letter It was November. Although it was not yet late, the sky was dark when I turned into Laundress Passage. Father had finished for the day, switched off the shop lights and closed the shutters; but so I would not come home to darkness he had left on the light over the stairs to the flat. Through the glass in the door it cast a foolscap rectangle of paleness onto the wet pavement, and it was while I was standing in that rectangle, about to turn my key in the door, that I first saw the letter. Another white rectangle, it was on the fifth step from the bottom, where I couldn't miss it. I closed the door and put the shop key in its usual place behind Bailey's Advanced Principles of Geometry. Poor Bailey. No one has wanted his fat gray book for thirty years. Sometimes I wonder what he makes of his role as guardian of the bookshop keys. I don't suppose it's the destiny he had in mind for the masterwork that he spent two decades writing. A letter. For me. That was something of an event. The crisp-cornered envelope, puffed up with its thickly folded contents, was addressed in a hand that must have given the postman a certain amount of trouble. Although the style of the writing was old-fashioned, with its heavily embellished capitals and curly flourishes, my first impression was that it had been written by a child. The letters seemed untrained. Their uneven strokes either faded into nothing or were heavily etched into the paper. There was no sense of flow in the letters that spelled out my name.";
    private interface ITester
    {
        Boolean IsConsonant(Char something);
    }

    // results in millisecs: 8378, 7980, 7533, 7752
    private class HashSetBasedTester : ITester
    {
        private HashSet<Char> hash;
        public HashSetBasedTester()
        {
            this.hash = new HashSet<Char>("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ");
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return this.hash.Contains(something);
        }
    }

    // results in millisecs: 6406, 6667, 6500, 6708
    private class HardcodedTester : ITester
    {
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return something == 'b' || something == 'c' || something == 'd' || something == 'f' || something == 'g' || something == 'h' || something == 'j' || something == 'k' || something == 'l' || something == 'm' || something == 'n' || something == 'p' || something == 'q' || something == 'r' || something == 's' || something == 't' || something == 'v' || something == 'w' || something == 'x' || something == 'z' ||
                something == 'B' || something == 'C' || something == 'D' || something == 'F' || something == 'G' || something == 'H' || something == 'J' || something == 'K' || something == 'L' || something == 'M' || something == 'N' || something == 'P' || something == 'Q' || something == 'R' || something == 'S' || something == 'T' || something == 'V' || something == 'W' || something == 'X' || something == 'Z';
        }
    }

    // WORST RESULTS
    // results in millisecs: 36585, 37702, ...
    private class ListBasedTester : ITester
    {
        private List<Char> list;
        public ListBasedTester()
        {
            this.list = new List<Char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z',
                'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z' };
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return this.list.Contains(something);
        }
    }

    // WINNER!
    // results in millisecs: 4716, 4846, 4756, 4550
    private class IndexBased : ITester
    {
        private Boolean[] map;
        private char min;
        private char max;
        public IndexBased()
        {
            var chars = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ".ToArray();
            this.min = chars.Min();
            this.max = chars.Max();
            var length = this.max - this.min + 1;
            this.map = new Boolean[length];
            foreach (var at in chars)
            {
                map[at - min] = true;
            }
        }
        public Boolean IsConsonant(Char something)
        {
            return something <= this.max && something >= this.min && this.map[something - this.min];
        }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        var tester = new IndexBased();//new IndexBased(); // new HashSetBasedTester(); // new HardcodedTester(); // new ListBasedTester(); //
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfRuns; i++)
        {
            foreach (var at in TextSample)
            {
                var tested = tester.IsConsonant(at);
            }
        }
        Trace.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need more than one argument if you're testing for more than one thing.

Comment: The best way IMO would be to use a case statement

Comment: Are you limited to English consonants and vowels, or do you need classifiers for every language?

Comment: @KirkWoll For unicode that would be a bad idea, but the question is about finding consonants from a set of characters, presumably the english alphabet.

Comment: I would suggest just keeping track of vowels and defining consonants as being not vowels, i.e. `IsConsonent(char c){return !IsVowel(c);}`

Comment: @Servy That works for English, but may not expand well into other languages. For example, soft `ь` and hard `ъ` signs of the Russian Cyrillic alphabet are neither vowels nor consonants.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight which is why I waited to add that comment until after the OP said that he only cared about english.

Comment: Until you test you don't know if Char.ToLower is more effient than putting both the upper and lower in the list or using string for IgnoreCase.

Answer (score 5):

[`HashSet<char>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) would do the trick. Create separate instances for consonants, vowels, etc., and use them to test membership.

```
ISet<char> vowels = new HashSet<char>("auoie");

if (vowels.Contains('a')) {
    // ...
}
```

**Update :** For English subset of characters you can build a `bool` array - similar to the one that you use in the update, but without the offset by `min`, and with upper/lower case duplication: it will be even faster - pretty much as fast as it gets.

```
private class IndexBased : ITester {
    private readonly bool[] map = new bool[128];
    public IndexBased() {
        foreach (var ch in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz") {
            map[ch] = map[Char.ToUpper(ch)] = true;
        }
    }
    public bool IsConsonant(Char ch) {
        return ch < map.Length && map[ch];
    }
}
```

Comment: Since OP has specified just English you could also hard code it.  It would be faster, but less extensible.

Comment: This is splitting hairs, but as a rule of thumb using a `HashSet` is great for lookups when you have more than 10 items.  Essentially, with really small collections the overhead of the backing hash table offsets any advantages.  As a test I tried using a `List<char>` instead and with a list of just 5 characters it was about 15% faster.

Comment: you're right there is no need in min boundary for english consonants and this way we will get the fastest results

Answer (score 1):

I gave dasblinenlight a +1 but if you need case insensitive then

```
private HashSet<string> vowels = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Might give better performance.

There is no fast easy case insensitive char comparison that I know of.   If there is please let me know.

I tried the following and it was a dead heat

> HashSet consonantHSchar = new HashSet 
>       {  'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
>          'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
>       List consonantListchar = new List 
>       {  'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
>          'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
>       HashSet consonantHSstring = new HashSet(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
>       {  "B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T","V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
>
> ```
> Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
>
> sw.Start();
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('b')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('b')");
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('m')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('m)");
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('z')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('z')");
> sw.Stop();
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
> sw.Restart();
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('b')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('b')");
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('m')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('m')");
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('z')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('z')");
> sw.Stop();
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
> sw.Restart();
> if (consonantHSstring.Contains("b")) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSstring.Contains('b')");
> if (consonantHSstring.Contains("m")) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSstring.Contains('m')");
> if (consonantHSstring.Contains("z")) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSstring.Contains('z')");
> sw.Stop();
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
> sw.Restart();
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('b')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('b')");
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('m')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('m')");
> if (consonantListchar.Contains('z')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantListchar.Contains('z')");
> sw.Stop();
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
> sw.Restart();
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('b')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('b')");
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('m')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('m)");
> if (consonantHSchar.Contains('z')) Debug.WriteLine("consonantHSchar.Contains('z')");
> sw.Stop();
> Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
> ```

Comment: @bonomo Come on, no ToLower() faster deserved a +1